# Why firebase return true even with empty input

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically the program should checks for the existance of the data in the Firebase database based on the input and display the pop up accordingly, but if I left the input as empty, somehow it still considered the data does exists by prompting the 'Request' pop-out window.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  final String input = mInput.getText().toString();

  DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  DatabaseReference idRef = rootRef.child("Patient");
  idRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      if (dataSnapshot.child(input).getValue() != null) {
          startActivity(new Intent(addNew.this, Request.class));
      } else{
          startActivity(new Intent(addNew.this, Fail.class));
      }
  }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
   });
}
```

I would like to know how to solve it so that the empty Input considered as inexistence data, thanks for the help

Comment: Describe your question

Comment: @KaranChunara  Everything goes well if I enter the inexistence data as it will prompt out the 'Fail' pop-out, but I am unsure why the program still prompt the 'Request' pop-out if I left the Input empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, just verify the lenght of the `input` String before you create the "Request pop-out window".

```
if(input.length() != 0) {
    //"Request pop-out window"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the value `!= null` but the thing is if the value is null, firebase does not create the that child node or deletes it. 
You can instead check `dataSnapshot.hasChild("input")` .